# I'm trying to remove values from a list but it says the value doesn't exist

Tags: python

```
example = [
    ('0-2', '0-0', '2-3', '0-1', '1-1', '1-0', '3-3', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'), 
    (4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 17, 20, 24, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 45, 48, 51, 58, 61, 71, 79), 
    ('4-2', '2-0', '0-1', '2-1', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'), 
    (6, 12, 13, 25, 30, 35, 37, 46, 47, 56, 58, '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-')
]

example.remove('-')

print(example)
```

```
    new_list.remove('-')
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

How should I proceed so that this error no longer occurs?

Expected result:

```
[
    ('0-2', '0-0', '2-3', '0-1', '1-1', '1-0', '3-3'), 
    (4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 17, 20, 24, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 45, 48, 51, 58, 61, 71, 79), 
    ('4-2', '2-0', '0-1', '2-1'), 
    (6, 12, 13, 25, 30, 35, 37, 46, 47, 56, 58)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_list` is this:

```
[('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('d', 'd', 'd', 'd')]
```

`'d'` isn't in it. Did you want?

```
new_list = [tup for tup in new_list if 'd' not in tup]
# [('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')]
```

In this case, we're checking if `'d'` is inside of each tuple in `new_list`

## Edit

Given the new problem formulation, what you want to do is filter the individual tuples. You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
example = [[item for item in tup if item != '-'] for tup in example]
```

Comment: A thousand apologies, but I had to increase the question because I was giving the wrong understanding about my need!

Comment: @BrondbyIF see my edit

Answer (score 3):

The items you want to remove are *not* in the list *example*, but in the tuples in the list. However, tuples are immutable, meaning that you cannot do `remove` on them. Instead, you can use (generator) comprehension to filter out unwanted items:

```py
example = [
    ('0-2', '0-0', '2-3', '0-1', '1-1', '1-0', '3-3', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'),
    (4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 17, 20, 24, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 45, 48, 51, 58, 61, 71, 79),
    ('4-2', '2-0', '0-1', '2-1', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'),
    (6, 12, 13, 25, 30, 35, 37, 46, 47, 56, 58, '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-')
]

output = [tuple(x for x in tup if x != '-') for tup in example]
print(output)
# [('0-2', '0-0', '2-3', '0-1', '1-1', '1-0', '3-3'), (4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 17, 20, 24, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 45, 48, 51, 58, 61, 71, 79), ('4-2', '2-0', '0-1', '2-1'), (6, 12, 13, 25, 30, 35, 37, 46, 47, 56, 58)]
```

Comment: Friend I would like to apologize for not marking your question as the solution, as the other guy offered to edit the answer that he had already tried to help before I edited the question for the new version. I gave you a positive vote to thank you! Hope you understand and keep the answer for more people to see!

Answer (score 1):

One best way would be to see what does `new_list` holds in the memory, like this...
[image]

Thus, as you can see, `new_list` holds, a **list of tuples**, that's why you're getting an error when you're trying to remove a single element 'd' from it.

Comment: A thousand apologies, but I had to increase the question because I was giving the wrong understanding about my need!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there is no `'d'` in the list is that the list is actually of tuppels of chars and not just of chars. You can see what a mean by this when you print the list before you remove `'d'`:

```
[('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('d', 'd', 'd', 'd')]
```

I asume you want to flatten the list and then remove the char. In this case you can do the following to actually flatten the list:

```
example = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

new_list = []

for nested in example:
    for item in nested:
        new_list.append(item)

new_list.remove('d')

print(new_list)
```

Comment: A thousand apologies, but I had to increase the question because I was giving the wrong understanding about my need!